# Hide one div if date inside another div is older than one year

Tags: jquery

I have a div class with date values:

```
<div class="order-date">May 6, 2013</div>
<div class="order-date">January 10, 2018</div>
<div class="order-date">April 10, 2019</div>
```

etc.

I would like to hide another div next to the date div:

```
<div class="download-link">Download proof">,
```

if the date in the .order-date div is older than one year.

Both these divs are inside a wrapper div, so it probably needs to be inside a loop?

```
<div class="account-ads-items">
    <div class="download-link">Download proof</div>
    <div class="order-date">May 6, 2013</div>
</div>

<div class="account-ads-items">
    <div class="download-link">Download proof</div>
    <div class="order-date">January 10, 2018/div>
</div>

<div class="account-ads-items">
    <div class="download-link">Download proof</div>
    <div class="order-date">April 10, 2019</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to find a solution with the new Date(); function, but couldn't come up with a good solution.

Comment: How specific are you wanting the "one year" check to be?  Only year?  Or are you looking specifically for 365 days to have passed?

Comment: Hi Tablar, yes, I'm looking for specifically for 356 days. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the ability to output the date as a data attribute like: data-date="YYYY-MM-DD" on the div?

Comment: imvain 2, no, unfortunately not.

Comment: Actually,  imvain2, I just checked again and yes, I can add an attribute like data-date="YYYY-MM-DD" to the div!! Thanks!

Comment: @Laura, once you have that parsing should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below loops through all order-date DIVs and reads their data. compares them with today-365 and hides the download link div.

```
$('.order-date').each(function() {
  let date = new Date($(this).text());
  let d = new Date();
  let old = date < (d.setDate(d.getDate() - 365)) ;

  if (old == true) {
    $(this).closest('.account-ads-items').find('.download-link').hide();
  }
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL4cq9sp/)

Answer (score 1):

Following should work for you,

```
$('.order-date').each(function(){
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var date_string = $(this).data('date'); 

    var parts =date_string.split('-');
    var date1 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
    var today = new Date();

    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - today.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    alert(diffDays);

    if( diffDays > 365 ){
        $(this).prev().hide();
    }

});
```